# Autocomplete form address from google maps

Tags: javascript, html, maps

Im develping register page for online shopping website

my idea: when the customer enter address instead of write it manually, he can select the location from the map and it will fill up the form automatically.

my problem is the code and every this is work probably but still cant fill up the forms for address like country and zip code and street address:

below here is the html code:

```html
<h3>CREATE A MEMBERSHIP ACCOUNT </h3>
<form  action="register.php" method="POST" novalidate="novalidate">
<div>
  <span >First Name</span>
  <input type="text"  id="first" name="fname"  required>  
</div>
<div>
    <span>Last Name</span>
    <input type="text" id="last" name="lname" required>
</div>
<div>
   <span >Username</span>
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required>      
</div>
<div >
    <span >Password</span>
     <input type="text" id="password" name="password" required>
</div>
<div>
      <span >Phone Number</span>
       <input type="text"  id="number" name="phone" required>
</div>
<div>
       <span >Email</span>
       <input type="text" id="email"   name="email" required>
 </div>
<div >
        <span >Country</span>
        <input type="text"  id="country" name="country" required>
 </div>
 <div>
        <span >City</span>
        <input type="text"  id="city" name="city"required>
 </div>
 <div >
        <span >State</span>
        <input type="text"  id="state" name="state" required>
</div>
<div>
        <span >Address</span>
        <input type="text"  id="location" name="address" required>
</div>
<div >
        <span >Post Code /ZIP</span>
        <input type="text"  id="postal_code" name="zip" rquired>
</div>
 </div>  
</div>
       <input  type="submit" name="create" value="Create an account">
</form>
</div>
<div >
      <input id="searchInput"  type="text" placeholder="Enter a location">
            <!-- Google map -->
            <div id="map"></div>
</div>
```

and this is js code:

```html
    <script>
    function initMap() {
        var myMapCenter = {lat: 3.0762757, lng: 101.547903};

        // Create a map object and specify the DOM element for display.
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: myMapCenter,
            zoom: 14
        });
        var input = document.getElementById('searchInput');
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
        autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
        });

        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
            infowindow.close();
            marker.setVisible(false);
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            if (!place.geometry) {
                window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
                return;
            }

            // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
                map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
                map.setZoom(17);
            }
            marker.setIcon(({
                url: place.icon,
                size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35)
            }));
            marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
            marker.setVisible(true);

            var address = '';
            if (place.address_components) {
                address = [
                  (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
                  (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
                  (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
                ].join(' ');
            }

            infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);

            // Location details
            for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
                if(place.address_components[i].types[0] == 'postal_code'){
                    document.getElementById('postal_code').innerHTML = place.address_components[i].long_name;
                }
                if(place.address_components[i].types[0] == 'country'){
                    document.getElementById('country').innerHTML = place.address_components[i].long_name;
                }
            }
            document.getElementById('location').innerHTML = place.formatted_address;
            document.getElementById('lat').innerHTML = place.geometry.location.lat();
            document.getElementById('lon').innerHTML = place.geometry.location.lng();
        });
    }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=AIzaSyDPOPMphz2ke-ILL8Xaxj0-yQUPpLskHVo&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

i hope someone lead me to solution that fix this problem 
thank you